# Load Map of Lists using Spring Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I want to load this from my properties file:

```
*.*.sherlock.reviewQuestionIds = "{
'SPARK_SELF_SERVE' : {
        'review-questions':[83021L, 82981L,83031L,83071L],
        'advertiserIndustry-question':[80351L],
        'productLine-question' : [83041L]
}
}";
```

Loading the data using :

```
@Value("#{'${sherlock.reviewQuestionIds}'.split(',')}")
private Map<CampaignType, Map<String, List<Long>>> questionsMapping;
```

Please help on this

Stack trace is : `[coral:launch] Exiting with throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerServiceConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map com.amazon.dadetcampaignprovider.spring.ProviderServiceConfig.questionsMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 8): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'SPARK_SELF_SERVE'
[coral:launch] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerServiceConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map com.amazon.dadetcampaignprovider.spring.ProviderServiceConfig.questionsMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 8): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'SPARK_SELF_SERVE'
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:843)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
[coral:launch]  at org.springframework.coral.CoralApplicationContext.refresh(CoralApplicationContext.java:203)
[coral:launch]  at com.amazon.coral.spring.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:119)
[coral:launch]  at com.amazon.coral.spring.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:72)`

Comment: Please give the whole file, code and error stackstrace

Comment: Hi Provided more details. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format is invalid

Try to change to this

```
{
  'ProgramName': {
    'review-questions': [
      '81L',
      '82L',
      '831L',
      '301L'
    ],
    'Industry-question': [
      '351L'
    ],
    'product-question': [
      '41L'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this catch. Updated. Please help n this

Comment: add the whole properties file. Still looks like your data is wrongly added/formatted

Comment: Updated. Please help